SQL/Postgre combining all tables from a schema
I have multiple tables - all with the same structure/columns but with different data. The structure is following:
"timestamp" timestamp,
company text,
division text,
team int,
request text,
value numeric,
source text

(The table structure is set for me. I haven't created it and I can't change it.)
All tables are in the same schema but neither I know the tables names nor their number (it is several tens of tables).
I need to create a DB view that would combine data from all tables with one specific change:

I need to add one more column to the view names customer. That column would combine company, division and team together (dash as separator).
Example if the company=A , division=B and team=1 than the new column customer would be A-B-1

I have already found pg_catalog.pg_tables:
SELECT string_agg(format('%s.%s AS %s', schemaname, tablename, tablename), ', ') INTO _tables
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
  WHERE schemaname = 'my_schema';

But I am unable to construct the working function and view.

Is the number/structure of tables constantly changing, or would this be a "one and done" thing?

Structure of all tables are the same and will remain the same.
Number of tables are dependant on external parameters (it can increase or decrease). It is expected to increase by appr 1-3 tables per month.

I have multiple tables - all with the same structure, that sounds like an issue with your datamodel. When using a 3NF data model, you wouldn't have the problem you're describing over here. Advice: Fix your data model.

I usually use union all to get data from multiple tables, and for a dynamic set of tables I need to use dynamic sql;
So; at first you need below function to run a dynamic sql query:
create or replace function public.exec(text) 
returns setof record language 'plpgsql' as $BODY$
begin
    return query execute $1;
end
$BODY$;

Then your query with union all will be created by this:
select regexp_replace(string_agg(format(
    'union all select *,"company"||''-''||"division"||''-''||"team" as "customer" from "%s"."%s"', schemaname, tablename, tablename), ' '), '^union all ', '') as "query"
from pg_catalog.pg_tables 
where schemaname = 'my_schema'

Consider
Now you can run that query by calling exec function like below:
select *
from exec((
    select regexp_replace(string_agg(format(
        'union all select *,"company"||''-''||"division"||''-''||"team" as "customer" from "%s"."%s"', schemaname, tablename, tablename), ' '), '^union all ', '') as "query"
    from pg_catalog.pg_tables 
    where schemaname = 'my_schema'
    )) as ("timestamp" timestamp, company text, division text, team int, request text, value numeric, source text, customer text)

I didn't test it but something like that would work -HTH ;)

You could simply use psql's \gexec.
